# SKShapeNode ellipseInRect, sprite does not appear in scene

Tags: sprite-kit, swift, ios8, skshapenode

I'm trying to create an ellipse in the center of my scene:

```
let center = (CGRectGetMidX(view.scene.frame), CGRectGetMidY(view.scene.frame))
let size = (view.scene.frame.size.width * 0.3, view.scene.frame.size.height * 0.3)
let ellipse = SKShapeNode (ellipseInRect: CGRectMake(center.0, center.1, size.0, size.1))
ellipse.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor()
ellipse.position = CGPointMake(center)
self.addChild(ellipse)
```

This was added to didMoveToView, and the node count on the view shows 1, but I do not see the path.  How do I add an ellipse to my scene using the `SKShapeNode ellipseInRect` API?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in `ellipse.position = CGPointMake(center)`. For some reason, this changes the position of the ellipse relative to itself rather than relative to the view - so if you did `ellipse.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)` then it would set the position to 100 up and 100 to the right of the ellipse itself as opposed to 100,100 on the scene. If you comment out this line, then you should be able to see you ellipse on the screen - I certainly could when it tried it. Hope that helps you position it to where you want.